# Four quadrant description

Tags: energy, automation

I am developing applications for energy automation for power generation and distribution utilities **but i dont have much electrical engineering background.**

I always have confusion when it comes to terms like phase angles lag,lead,import and export
and four quadrants.

Can someone please explain a **Four quadrant system** considering the **power systems**?

**I want to know what happens when a phase angle falls into a quadrant (such as import/export,lag/lead,inductive/capacitive  etc.)**

Comment: Do you want to hear about it in theory, or do you want some explanation of the algorithms engineers use when doing numeric calculations like in your application? Like how to calculate phase difference from two samples, effective value and so on?

Comment: @Kurtovic,thank you for the reply.I prefer to know theory behind it first so that i have basic foundation.

Comment: Alright, then may answer was track on. If you need some further elaborations drop a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume your phasors rotate in a technically positive direction(counter-clock). So the phasors will be a representation of passed time in regard to the \$x\$ axis. Lets look at it through the formula:
$$ \underline{I}=Ie^{j\varphi}$$
is actually a representation of:
$$ I(t)=I\sqrt{2}[\cos(\omega t +\varphi)+j\sin(\omega t + \varphi)] $$
A deeper theoretical elaboration can be found at [this link.](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Phasor)

You usually represent current and voltage in a phasor diagram. You can represent reactive and active power too, but that won't be called a phasor diagram in strict interpretation.
It is usual to put the voltage \$\underline{U}\$ as reference on the \$x\$-axis. Doing this we simplify the representation without loss of generality. So our basic system will be:
$$\underline{U}=Ue^{j0^o}\\
\underline{I}=Ie^{j\varphi}$$
The phase angle will be put next to the current so that we have a framework for describing phase differences.

There are three basic kinds of impedances: Restive(\$\mathcal{Z}_R\$), Capacitive(\$\mathcal{Z}_C\$) and inductive(\$\mathcal{Z}_L\$). Combinations are possible of course. They are represented as:
$$\mathcal{Z}_R=R=\mathfrak{Re}\{R\}\\
\mathcal{Z}_C=X_Ce^{-j90^o}=\frac{1}{j\omega C}\\
\mathcal{Z}_L=X_Le^{j90^o}=j\omega L$$
The generalised impedance can be represented as:
$$\mathcal{Z}=R+jX=|\mathcal{Z}|e^{-j\varphi}$$
You should now ask why does the argument of \$\mathcal{Z}\$ has a minus sign. The reason behind this is:
$$\underline{I}=\frac{Ue^{j0^o}}{|\mathcal{Z}|e^{-j\varphi}}\\
\underline{I}=Ie^{j\varphi}$$

Lets now describe the terminology that is used for this system:

- Inductive: Means that your load is of dominantly inductive character. The current will lag behind the voltage so the phase angle will be \$-90^o<\varphi<0 \$. Differential equation for inductor: \$u_L(t)=L\frac{\mathbb{d}i_L}{\mathbb{d}t}\$.
- Capacitive: Means that your load is of dominantly capcitive character. The voltage will lag behind the current so the phase angle will be \$0^o<\varphi<90^o \$. Differential equation for capacitor: \$i_c(t)=C\frac{\mathbb{d}u_c}{\mathbb{d}t}\$.
- Resistive: Only the real part exists. \$\varphi=0\$
  Angles that are in \$(90^o,270^0)\$ represent only that the flow direction of current is inverse, meaning \$\underline{I}=-\underline{I}_{negative}\$. Here is a graph for a capacitive resistive load, the amplitudes of \$U,I,\mathcal{Z}\$ are arbitary as the units are different.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhcsXO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to calculating power, voltage is multiplied by current and, this should be done in real time using instantaneous values. A 4 quadrant multiplier is used and quite simply this means both positive and negative values of both voltage and current, produce the correct numerical result. This is different to a 2 quadrant multiplier in that one of the signals must always remain positive such as in broadcast AM transmission.

For a resistive load, there is real power and voltage and current are in phase ie there is no lead or lag. For a partially or fully reactive load, current will lead or lag the voltage ie when viewed on an o-scope the current will appear to be time-shifted with respect to voltage.

Regards import or export I confess I have no idea what the relevance is to the question.